# Query for requirement description changes after a given date

Tags: azure-devops

I wonder is is possible to query all the requirements which have had their "Description" changed after a given date?

We had requirements which changed during the course of development and I want to find all those items.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder is is possible to query all the requirements which have had
> their "Description" changed after a given date?

Sorry but I'm afraid we don't support this out-of-box feature. We can't query the requirements which have had their "Description" changed after a given date. See available fields:

[image]

What you need is something like `Description Changed Date` field with `Was Ever` operator. But for now this field is not supported, you can submit a feature request on our [User Voice forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) if you do want this feature. Our team would consider your feedback seriously if it gets enough votes.

Comment: Thanks Lance, I submitted the feature request.

Comment: You can share the link here, and people interested in that would vote for you. And if my answer helps to resolve your original question about whether it's possible, you could [accepting it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).